# Making my program more modular made it slower

Tags: c#

I wrote a run-once program to read data from one table and migrate what was read into several other tables (using LINQ).  It was one Main() method that extracted the data, transformed it where needed, converted some fields, etc. and inserted the data into the appropriate tables.  Basically, just migrating data from one format to another.  The program would take about 5 minutes to run, but it did what I needed.

While looking at the program, I thought I'd break up the huge Main() method into smaller chunks.  Basically, I just refactored areas of the code and extracted them to methods.

The program still does what it's supposed to, migrate data, but it takes twice as long now, if not longer.

So, my question is: Do method calls slow down processing?  None of the code itself changed, other than being put inside its own method.

Comment: Have you performed any actual benchmarking?  It could be something outside of the program.

Comment: The first rule of performance is that "we should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil", per Knuth. The second rule is that only an actual measurement of an actual program has much bearing on what that actual program's performance characteristics will be, so measure everything!

Comment: Another thought... you mentioned data.  How is the data stored/passed from method to method?  I'm not sure what your structure is, but it could be that you're suffering from an overhead of having to copy large collections between methods?  Then there's GC to worry about, depending on how much "big data" you're dealing with.

Comment: If it involves lot of data transformation, can this be moved close to the place where the data resides, say transformation within a stored proc?

Comment: It is very unlikely that the rearranging itself caused a 3 fold increase in runtime. More likely is that you've accidentally introduced some kind of inefficiency into your code at the Linq (Entity Framework) level. Try adding a SQL profiler on. I suspect that you are either Lazy loading, or have introduced multiple iterations of an `IEnumerable`/`IQueryable`, resulting in rewinds/multiple queries. If its the former, use `.Include` to eager load. If its the latter, use `.ToList()` to concrete up the query, before you iterate over it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, function calls generally have a cost but it's not usually very high unless your code has been refactored to a point where every function has only one line, or you're calling them billions of times :-)

The question you have to ask yourself is: do the benefits outweigh the cost?

Modularising your code will almost certainly make it easier to maintain, unless it's some Mickey-Mouse Hello-World type of program.

The *other* question you have to ask is, if it's run-once, why did you bother trying to improve it? If five minutes is acceptable, then the effort you spent improving it seems like a sunk cost to me. If it's going to be used a lot, or by many other people, that's one thing. But, if you're only running it (for example) once a month, why bother?

If you really want to know where the bottlenecks are, Microsoft have spent some time [making it easy for you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9z62c29%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

---

Though not a huge sample, consider the following C program (since that's my area of expertise):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void xyzzy(int argc, char *argv[]) {}
int main (void) {
    int x = argc;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 1000000; j++) {
            x = x + 1;
            //xyzzy();
        }
    }
    printf ("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled (without any optimisation since I don't want the compiler second-guessing me, and using trickery to reduce the chances of the compiler weaving any magic *before* running the code), the figures I get for with and without the function call (five separate runs each, using `sys+user` times from the `time` command) are:

```
   with  without
-------  -------
  2.452    2.264
  2.451    2.358
  2.468    2.342
  2.390    2.233
  2.374    2.249
-------  -------
 12.135   11.446 total
  2.468    2.358 max
  2.374    2.233 min
```

So what can we tell from that, apart from the fact I'm a lousy statistician? :-)

It appears, based on the total that the one without the function call is about 6% faster. It's also telling that the fastest run with the function call is still slower than the slowest run without it.

Comment: I basically 'modularized' it as an exercise.  The program will never be maintained, it was just a tool to move some data.  So, ease of maintenance isn't an issue.  I just thought it odd how much slower the program was after adding the method calls.